# Не правильно работает булева функция

Tags: c++

Моя функция  должна проверять однаковы  ли два компонента. Но  она всегда false возвращает. Я  думаю проблема в  этой строчке:

```
 if (!test1->equals(test2->child(childIndex)))
```

но я  не  знаю как  ее по другому переписать

Функция

```
  bool Test::equals(const Component* comp) const
  {
     const Test* test1 = dynamic_cast<const Test*>(this);
     const Test* test2 = dynamic_cast<const Test*>(comp);
     if ((test1 != nullptr) && (test2 != nullptr))
     {
        if (test1->name() != test2->name())
           return false;
        if (test1->numChildren() != test2->numChildren())
           return false;
        for (decltype(test1->numChildren()) childIndex = 0; childIndex < test1->numChildren(); ++childIndex)
        {
            if (!test1->equals(test2->child(childIndex)))
               return false;
        }
        return true;
     }
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: `test1->name()` ??

Comment: Ещё надо `if (test1 == test2) return true;` в начало функции.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Неэквивалетно получится. В исходном варианте `null != null` :)

Comment: @AnT, вот именно для исправления этого бага и надо дописать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что именно и как вы собираетесь сравнивать - это у вас надо спрашивать. Что вы сейчас сравниваете - то вам ваша функция и возвращает.

1. Смущает часть, где вы переходите к просмотру неких `test2->child(childIndex)`, но при этом все равно сравниваете всех их с `test1`. Мое гадание на кофейной гуще подсказывает мне, что раз уж вы c правой стороны перешли к `test2->child(childIndex)`, то и с левой стороны надо было бы перейти к `test1->child(childIndex)`

   ```
   if (!test1->child(childIndex)->equals(test2->child(childIndex)))
     return false;
   ```

   Однако возникает вопрос: а значение какого типа у вас возвращает эта функция `child()`? Подозреваю, что так просто все не получится и именно поэтому вы "не знаете как ее по другому переписать".
2. Вот это

   ```
   const Test* test1 = dynamic_cast<const Test*>(this);
   ```

   является бессмысленным `dynamic_cast`, т.е. это пустая операция, эквивалентная

   ```
   const Test* test1 = this;
   ```
3. Умный компилятор, принимая во внимание пункт 2, может выкинуть проверку

   ```
   if ((test1 != nullptr) && ...
   ```

   из первого `if`, т.к. `this` никогда не может быть нулевым указателем. Поэтому если у вас `test1->child(childIndex)` может вернуть нулевой указатель, то не надейтесь, что эта проверка вас защитит.

Comment: нет  не может вернуть нулевой  указатель.  Если использовать на примере мою функцию: QVERIFY(test.child(0)->equals(task1.get())); я так  записываю. Оно  должно true возвратить так как task1 есть  дитем test и оно по индексом  0 знаходится, но возвращает  false

Comment: функция Component* Test::child(size_t index)
{
    return mComponents[index].get();
}

Answer (score 3):

```
        if (!test1->child(childIndex)->equals(test2->child(childIndex)))
           return false;
```